# Filter lists with LINQ

Tags: c#, list, linq, generics, lambda

I have, list `Students` and `Teachers`

```
var students = new List<Student>
    {
        new Student
        {
            Id= 1,
            Name = "AA",
            City = "London",
            Country = "UK"
        },
        new Student
        {
            Id= 2,
            Name = "BB",
            City = "New Orleans",
            Country = "USA"
        }
    }

var teachers = new List<Teacher>
    {
        new Teacher
        {
            Id = 1,
            Name = "CC",
            City = "Berlin",
            Country = "Germany"
        },
        new Teacher
        {
            Id = 2,
            Name = "DD",
            City = "Mexico D.F.",
            Country = "Mexico"
        }
    }
```

I wanted, for each teacher, get a list of students located in the same country and the same city.

What I did so far:

```
var result = from teacher in teachers
                     select new
                     {
                         teacher,
                         Students = students.Where(s => s.Country == teacher.Country && s.City == teacher.City).ToList()
                     };
```

This not worked, I got `casting exception`. And tried with:

```
var result = new List<(Teacher, IEnumerable<Student>)>();

teachers.ToList().ForEach(c => result.Add((c,
        students.Where(s => s.Country == c.Country && s.City == c.City).ToList())));
```

This worked fine but, is there any other ways, without looping?

Comment: Yes, this is very do-able with LINQ only. The foreach is not necessary. Using a combination of `Select` and `Where` you can get the result you want. `var teachersWithStudents = teachers.Select(teacher => new { teacher, Students = students.Where(s => s.Country == teacher.Country && s.City == teacher.City).ToList() }).ToList()`

Comment: Just to clarify, linq is a foreach too and when you do ToList you loop throw all the list the same  :) but yah @nbokmans solution should work

Comment: @nbokmans got `System.InvalidCastException : Unable to cast object of type System.Collections.Generic.List1[<>f__AnonymousType02[Teacher, System.Collections.Generic.List1[Student]]] to type System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable1[System.ValueTuple2[Teacher,System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable1[Student]]]'.`

Comment: @Alen.Toma I believe @nbokmans referenced to the `.Tolist().ForEach(...)` in OP's question. As speaking of: `ForEach(...)` is a void method of `List<T>` and actually a syntactic sugar to `foreach (x in y) {}`, has nothing to do with LINQ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your linq query is correct. Your query returns a list of anonymous type. You cannot cast it directly to a tuple list.
The problem you have is which type you are trying to cast to. If you are trying to get a result of Tuple list like IEnumerable<(Teacher, IEnumerable)> you should code as below:

```
        var result = from teacher in teachers
                     select (
                         teacher,
                         students.Where(s => s.Country == teacher.Country && s.City == teacher.City).ToList()
                         );
```

Then,
result.ToList() would give you a List of Tuple,
result.ToArray() would give you an array of Tuple

Lambda expression alternative:

```
var result = teachers
            .Select(teacher => (teacher, students.Where(s => s.Country == teacher.Country && s.City == teacher.City).ToList()));
```

However, I would prefer anonymous list as a return type rather than Tuple.